# Prevent Alert View from cancelling Long Press Gesture

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uialertview, long-press

I have a UILongPressGestureRecognizer that detects 3 second presses, in order to get the app into edit mode. Sometimes it can happen that an alertview pops up during that time, due to other things going on in the app. When that happens, the user could abandon the long press, and handle the alert. But it must also be possible for the user to keep pressing, and the app needs to go into edit mode even with the alert still there (the app will then dismiss the alert itself).

However, when the UIAlertView pops up, the OS automatically cancels all ongoing gestures, thereby shortcutting the long press. The GestureRecognizer receives a `touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`. By setting breakpoint in XCode I can clearly see that it is caused by the UIAlertView popping up.

Does anybody know whether this can be prevented, or knows a work-around?

This is for iOS-7 if it makes a difference.

Comment: who handles the alertview?

Comment: What do you mean with "handles the alerview"? The alertview pops up, and is not handled yet. Or do you mean which class shows the alertview? Why could that be relevant?

Comment: how did you overcome this..?

Comment: @AhmedZ. I didn't. I would still appreciate a way around this.

Comment: @fishinear my scenario was alerts while press and holding a button, so i created an option to either cancel alerts while user is holding button or cancel the hold on alert.

Comment: @AhmedZ. Unfortunately that won't help for me. In my case, a short press will do some action that may pop up an alert, but holding on for longer should cancel the alert.